# Is $L = \{w w^r w | w \in a(b+c)^*a \}$ a context-free language?

Tags: context-free, pumping-lemma

Can't understand how to apply pumping lemma to see if a language is context-free or not.

I tried to verify the context-free's pumping lemma, and the language seems to be not context-free but I can't understand if I'm correct. I tried writing all factorizations, but I don't know when I have to stop or if there's a way to understand immediately if it isn't context-free. Is this language context-free?

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/156700/755, https://stackoverflow.com/q/75059431/781723.  please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).  If you realize you have posted your question on the wrong site, you can delete the old copy before posting on a new site.

Answer (score 0):

Assume $L$ is context-free and let $n$ be its pumping length. Let $u = ab^naab^naab^na = (ab^na)^3$. Since $(ab^na)^R = ab^na$, it is clear that $u\in L$. That means, since $|u| \geqslant n$, that the there exists a decomposition $u = vwxyz$ such that:

1. $|wxy|\leqslant n$;
2. $wy\neq \varepsilon$;
3. for $k\geqslant 0$, $vw^kxy^kz\in L$.

- Since a word of $L$ contains exactly $6$ $a$'s, $wy$ contains only $b$'s (otherwise you could pump to get more than $6$ $a$'s).
- If $wxy$ is contained in one of the $3$ sequences of $b$'s in $u$ and you pump it, it will create an imbalance in the number of $b$'s, for example you will get $ab^maab^naab^na$ with $m>n$, which is clearly not a word of the language.
- That means that $w$ is contained in one sequence, and $y$ in another sequence. But again, pumping it will create a word (for example) $ab^maab^paab^na$ with $m>n$ and $p > n$, which is again not in the language.

By contradiction, we can conclude that the language is not context-free.